# Excel - Copy rows from one sheet to another sheet based in a criteria without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel with the next structure in the first sheet

| ID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | red | A |
| 002 | green | A |
| 002 | blue | A |
| 002 | blue | B |

I need the rows whose color is blue to be automatically copied to the second sheet(including the records that are later included in the first sheet) with only formulas without VBA

With the example

| ID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 002 | blue | A |
| 002 | blue | B |

I try to use the nex formula in the second sheet

```
=IF('Sheet1'!$B2="blue";'Sheet1'!A2;"")
```

and i got the following result

| ID | Color | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
|  |  |  |
| 002 | blue | A |
| 002 | blue | B |

but i need the unmatched rows not to appear even blank

is there any way to do this if VBA?

I use Excel 2010

Many thanks to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible without VBA as well if you use additional column in "Sheet1", for example "D" for your table. In "D1" write "Counter"
Then write in "D2":

```
=IF(B2="blue";MAX($D$1:D1)+1;0)
```

and copy to rows below.
This is an increasing counter of rows with blue values in B2 or 0.

Then in new sheet "Sheet2" copy header line ("ID", "Color, "Size") from "Sheet1" to "A1:C1".

In "A2" write:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$100;MATCH(ROW()-1;Sheet1!$D$2:$D$100;COLUMN());"")
```

Copy "A2" cell through "C2", then whole line "A2:C2" until last row.

These functions look for ROW()-1 in "D" column of "Sheet1" and show the whole row if found. IFERROR hide other rows, because if not found #N/A will be shown in empty cells within your range.

$A$2:$C$100 - your source table in "Sheet1".
$D$2:$D$100 - counters' range.

Comment: It works but repeat the last row when has no more data. Any solution for this?

Comment: @Blrackerd, check ranges and check if they are absolute (with $) and the same in whole table. Can you show me the screenshot?